# PHP seems to ignore the default OpenSSL config

Tags: php, openssl

I need to change the OpenSSL config used by PHPs openssl* methods. phpinfo() reports the default openssl config as present in /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf. However, it does not seem to use it.

I changed the openssl.cnf to have some invalid values in it. Running openssl from the shell righfully fails and complains about an invalid config. The openssl* methods in my PHP script still continue to work?! They should fail with the same error message.

So, what OpenSSL config is PHP actually using?

PHP is running as Apache2 module in an Alpine Linux Docker Container (Package php81-apache2)

Comment: Run `phpinfo();` and then look at the parameter `Openssl default config` in the `openssl` section

Comment: I did that and changed the file. No effect. Restarted the container to make sure it is not cached somewhere

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some caching involved (have to investigate later). After letting the system sit for a few hours the PHP methods used the changed configuration.

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I even restarted the whole container. That is why it's odd. Most likely the error was on my side though :-)